# kendoui panelbar format text with color and underline

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I'm trying to format the kendoui panelbar text only, not the content inside the container.

```
    /* kendo overrides */
    .k-panelbar .k-link
    {
        font-size:larger;
        font-weight:700;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

The code above leaves the content in the panel intact, and formats the text in the panel bar with all but the text-decoration option.

text-decoration (tried text-decoration-color as well) doesn't work unless I use .k-item, but k.item affects the content in the panel as well.

```
    /* kendo overrides */
    .k-panelbar .k-item
    {
        font-size:larger;
        font-weight:700;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

How do I change only the text in the panelbar itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
.k-panelbar>.k-item>.k-link {
      color: red !important;
      text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

You want to change apply style only to panelbar header.

Let me know if I am not understand your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. This is great, except I cannot underline. Is that being overwritten from somewhere else?

Comment: I have updated above code snippet and its works perfectly from my side. Can you please temporary remove another style and css file and check it.

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect! I haven't seen the !important code before, but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks again.